# Why are my monthly and quarterly rep scores showing as equal?

Tags: bug, reputation

From the [monthly rep leagues](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month) ("2016-08-01 to today"):

[image: month]

From the [quarterly rep leagues](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter) ("2016-07-01 to today"):

[image: quarter]

My rep gained in the month and quarter are both showing up as exactly the same, even though I know this isn't true - I did have a net gain rep during July.

The same problem is affecting the users Aegon and Thaddeus Howze, and maybe others too. (I haven't checked their reputation graph to see if they actually did have a net rep gain in July, but I assume they did.)

**What's going on here? Is there a bug in the rep leagues that only affects certain users?**

<sub>Or am I being stupid and missing something?</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See: [Something wrong with monthly user rep - some users show quarterly figures?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281997/something-wrong-with-monthly-user-rep-some-users-show-quarterly-figures/283293#283293)

tl;dr: we forgot to reset the counter on monthly rep this month. It should be correct again come September.

Comment: You forgot to reset a counter? I thought you guys used computers? Can't you program them to do stuff like that automatically?